# Engineers end of game victory point stronghold

Tags: terra-mystica

When an Engineer builds a Stronghold they get 3 victory points for each bridge. My question is when the game ends do they get this victory point bonus for each bridge again?

I'm kinda confused because the rule book says the end-of-turn bonus cards do NOT yield their bonuses on the final round. I'm wondering if the same rule applies for favor tiles and the Engineer-bridge victory points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bonus cards the rule book is referring to are the cards that flip at the beginning of each round (each with one ongoing effect and one end-of-round bonus effect).

It's simply stating that the final end-of-turn bonus effect does not apply on the final round (hence the tiny half-bonus card they provide you with to cover up the second half).